How to change the sub class method return type without override or generic?
The code like bellow:
interface INode {
    getChildren(): INode[];
}

class NodeImpl implements INode {
    getChildren(): INode[] {
        return [];
    }
}

interface IComp extends INode {
    otherMethod(): void;
    /**@override */
    getChildren(): IComp[];
}

//Class 'Comp' incorrectly implements interface 'IComp'.
class Comp extends NodeImpl implements IComp {
    otherMethod() { }

    // this work but have runtime effect
    // override getChildren() {
    //     return super.getChildren() as IComp[];
    // }
}

const c = new Comp();
const children = c.getChildren(); // type of `children` should be `IComp[]`

playground link
In my actual scenario, generics cannot be used, so generics are not considered.

You're trying to narrow getChildren without reimplementing it? Looks like you might want the declare modifier as shown in this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate. If not, what's missing?

@jcalz, thanks for your reply. This change will make 'getChildren' a property member instead of a function member, so I won't be able to override it in the subclass. See this link

Without ms/TS#48290 you cannot declare a method. Would declaration merging like this playground link work instead for you?

@jcalz thanks! Declaration merging work for me

Right now the only way I know of to do this is via declaration merging, where you re-open the Comp instance interface and add your desired getChildren() call signature:
class Comp extends NodeImpl implements IComp {
    otherMethod() { }
}
interface Comp {
    getChildren(): IComp[];
}


Ideally you'd be able to instead use the declare modifier like
// Don't try this, not valid TS
class Comp extends NodeImpl implements IComp {
    otherMethod() { }
    declare getChildren(): IComp[];    
}

since that works for properties and has the intended semantics of narrowing a subclass member without reimplementing it. But for now that use of declare is forbidden on methods. You could rewrite it to look like a function-valued property instead of a method, like
class Comp extends NodeImpl implements IComp {
    otherMethod() { }
    declare getChildren: () => IComp[];    
}

but then subclasses of Comp wouldn't be able to override getChildren with method syntax.
There's an open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#48290 to allow using declare with methods. Until and unless that is implemented, you'll need to use declaration merging instead.
Playground link to code
